# Eliminate $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ from the system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Eliminate $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ from the following system of equations.

$$a\cos(\alpha)+b\cos(\beta)+c\cos(\gamma)=0$$
$$a\sin(\alpha)+b\sin(\beta)+c\sin(\gamma)=0$$
$$a\sec(\alpha)+b\sec(\beta)+c\sec(\gamma)=0$$

My try:

Squaring and adding first two equations, we get:

$$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{c^2-a^2-b^2}{2ab}$$

$$\cos(\gamma-\beta)=\frac{a^2-c^2-b^2}{2cb}$$

$$\cos(\alpha-\gamma)=\frac{b^2-a^2-c^2}{2ac}$$

Now the RHS of above all looks like negative cosines of triangle $\Delta ABC$.

But I am not sure whether it will help.

This question is taken from plane trigonometry part 1 by SL Loney book. Page number 264, question number 176.

Comment: I think the first equation does not fit the sequence.

Comment: Considering you tagged it with triangles, is alpha beta gamma angles of a triangle?

Comment: This problem is from Trigonometry by S.L.Loney

Comment: @Umeshshankar I have SL loney, please give pase number, and questions number.

Comment: @Umeshshankar also please use @[my_username] to notify me

Comment: @user541396 its page 264 and Problem 176, but mine is indian publication. Its actually the problem from miscellaneous exercises.

Comment: It's hard to know what the author expects here; you might say something about what topics Loney covers near this problem. That said, a brute force approach (with complex exponentials and resultants) gives $$abc(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)=0$$ (some of whose factors may be extraneous) without assuming any relation among the angles. Perhaps the point is to calculate coefficient matrix' determinant, and to see that it simplifies to $$\sin(\alpha-\beta)\sin(\beta-\gamma)\sin(\gamma-\alpha)\sec\alpha\sec\beta\sec\gamma$$ If that's non-zero, then $a=b=c=0$; if it's zero, you get special cases.

Comment: @Blue answer is $$ a^4 + b^4+c^4 - 2b^2 c^2 - 2a^2c^2- 2b^2a^2 = 0 $$

Comment: @Blue this is miscellaneous examples (unsolved). However there is a chapter by the name of elimination. I will study it tomorrow to see if something is relevant.

Comment: @user541396: It's worth noting that the answer in your comment factors into the last four terms in my comment (it's like Heron's formula, except that $a$, $b$, $c$ are centroid-to-vertex distances instead of sides), so there's some consistency. :)

Comment: @Blue if you use the formula for $$ {( a + b + c )}^2 $$ to factorise the solution, you get $$ a = b + c $$  $$b = c+a $$ and $$ c = b + a $$ thus $$ a + b + c = 0 $$ assuming a,b,c are positive.

Comment: @user541396: I'm not sure I understand your point. Factoring certainly gives $(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)=0$. Thus, we have get independent possibilities $a=b+c$, $b=c+a$, $c=a+b$, and $a+b+c=0$, but not necessarily all (or even more-than-one) at the same time.

Comment: @Umeshshankar, see if my answer meets your requirements, if not please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

From equation $$a\sin(\alpha)+b\sin(\beta)+c\sin(\gamma)=0$$
$$a\sec(\alpha)+b\sec(\beta)+c\sec(\gamma)=0$$
using cross-multiplication:

$$\frac{a}{\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\gamma}-\frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\beta}}=\frac{b}{\frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\alpha}-\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\gamma}}=\frac{c}{\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta}-\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha}}=k$$

Using this and putting the value in equation $a\cos(\alpha)+b\cos(\beta)+c\cos(\gamma)=0$ ,

$$\cos\alpha \left(\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\gamma}-\frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\beta}\right)+\cos\beta \left(\frac{\sin\gamma}{\cos\alpha}-\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}\right)+\cos\gamma \left(\frac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\beta}-\frac{\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha}\right)=0$$

Which simplifies to,

$$\cos^2\alpha(\sin2\beta-\sin2\gamma)+\cos^2\beta(\sin2\gamma-\sin2\alpha)+\cos^2\gamma(\sin2\alpha-\sin2\beta)=0$$

$$(\cos2\alpha+1)(\sin2\beta-\sin2\gamma)+(\cos2\beta+1)(\sin2\gamma-\sin2\alpha)+(\cos2\gamma+1)(\sin2\alpha-\sin2\beta)=0$$

Which simplifies to,

$$\sin(\alpha-\beta) \sin(\beta-\gamma) \sin(\gamma-\alpha)=0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(i)$$

In equations $1$ and $2$, shift the $\cos$ terms to other side and square both sides ,
adding them we get,

$$a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(\alpha-\beta)=c^2$$

Which gives the value of

$$\cos(\alpha-\beta)=\frac{c^2-a^2-b^2}{2ab}$$

From this we get the value of $\sin(\alpha-\beta)$ by using $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

Similarly we can get to $\sin(\beta-\gamma)$ and $\sin(\gamma-\alpha)$

Putting them in equation (*i*) and squaring, we get

$$a^4+b^4+c^4-2b^2c^2-2a^2b^2-2c^2a^2=0$$

Answer (score 2):

We have the following system of equations
\begin{align}
a\cos(\alpha)+b\cos(\beta)+c\cos(\gamma) &= 0, \tag{1}\\
a\sin(\alpha)+b\sin(\beta)+c\sin(\gamma) &= 0, \tag{2}\\
a\sec(\alpha)+b\sec(\beta)+c\sec(\gamma) &= 0. \tag{3}
\end{align}

From (1) and (2), we have
$$a^2 + b^2 + 2ab \cos \alpha\cos \beta + 2ab \sin \alpha \sin \beta = c^2$$
and thus
$$(2ab)^2\sin^2 \alpha \sin^2\beta = (c^2 - a^2 - b^2 - 2ab\cos \alpha\cos \beta)^2. \tag{4}$$

From (1) and (3), we have
$$a^2 + b^2 + ab\frac{\cos \alpha}{\cos \beta} + ab \frac{\cos \beta}{\cos \alpha} = c^2$$
and thus
$$(2ab)^2(\cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2\beta) = 2\cdot (c^2 - a^2 - b^2)\cdot 2ab \cos \alpha \cos \beta. \tag{5}$$

$(4) + (5)$ gives
$$(2ab)^2(1 + \cos^2\alpha \cos^2\beta ) = (c^2 - a^2 - b^2)^2 + (2ab)^2 \cos^2 \alpha \cos^2 \beta$$
and thus
$$(2ab)^2 = (c^2 - a^2 - b^2)^2$$
which can be written as
$$- a^4 - b^4 - c^4 + 2a^2b^2 + 2b^2c^2 + 2c^2a^2 = 0$$
or
$$(a + b + c)(a + b - c)(b + c - a)(c + a - b) = 0.$$

We are done.